# Maintain order in jsonb_array_elements after filtering elements

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-order-by, jsonb

Having this query

```
SELECT id, listing -> 'description' AS description, listing -> 'vin' AS vin
FROM public.listings,
     jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'attributes' -> 'listings') listing
WHERE id = '12070'
  AND listing -> 'vin' ?| array ['0HSDZTZR9LN000000','3HSDZTZR9LN056080']
```

I get this result

```
12070,"Pie","3HSDZTZR9LN056080"
12070,"Soda","0HSDZTZR9LN000000"
```

Is there a way to maintain the same order as the one provided in the array for filtering? `array ['0HSDZTZR9LN000000','3HSDZTZR9LN056080']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatically.  You can just add an ORDER BY to put it into order, but this will require repeating yourself to some extent as the array would be provided twice:

```
SELECT id, listing -> 'description' AS description, listing -> 'vin' AS vin
FROM public.listings,
     jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'attributes' -> 'listings') listing
WHERE id = '12070'
  AND listing -> 'vin' ?| array ['0HSDZTZR9LN000000','3HSDZTZR9LN056080']
ORDER BY array_position( array ['0HSDZTZR9LN000000','3HSDZTZR9LN056080'], listing ->> 'vin');
```